# How to take value based on previous node from the given xml file

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an xml file shown below which is small part of big xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xn:VsDataContainer id=test">
  <xn:attributes>
    <xn:vsDataType>vsDataEUtranCellFDD</xn:vsDataType>
    <es:crsGain>0</es:crsGain>
    <es:pciConflictCell>
      <es:enbId>66111</es:enbId>
      <es:cellId>3</es:cellId>
    </es:pciConflictCell>
    <es:pdcchLaGinrMargin>100</es:pdcchLaGinrMargin>
    <es:lbEUtranAcceptOffloadThreshold>50</es:lbEUtranAcceptOffloadThreshold>
    <es:pdcchCfiMode>5</es:pdcchCfiMode>
    <es:cellId>0</es:cellId>
    <es:zzzTemporary21>-2000000000</es:zzzTemporary21>
  </xn:attributes>
</xn:VsDataContainer>
```

I am using following code to get values of `crsGain` and `cellId`.But `cellId`iam not getting the desired one.. ie i need `cellId` if the previous node is `pdcchCfiMode` .so here i should get value as 0 ,but i am getting 3 which is the first in the sequence .How to solve this issue.Snippet Code i am using is

```
if (vsDataEUtranCellFDD.Any()) {
    List<CellName> cells = vsDataEUtranCellFDD.Select(x => new CellName() {
        cellId= (int)x.Descendants().Where(a => a.Name.LocalName == "cellId").FirstOrDefault(),
        crsGain = (int)x.Descendants().Where(a => a.Name.LocalName == "crsGain").FirstOrDefault(),
```

**EDIT**

this cellid can happen in middle also ,only differentiation is previous node which is pdcchCfiMode

Comment: this cellid can happen in middle also ,only differentiation is previous node which is pdcchCfiMode

Comment: Can you guarantee that after every `pdcchCfiMode`, the `cellid` happens always?

Comment: yea 100% gauratee

Comment: OK. Check my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [skip the elements while](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549075(v=vs.110).aspx) they are not equal to `pdcchCfiMode` then take the first element. Something like this:

```
cellId = (int)x.Descendants().SkipWhile(a => a.Name.LocalName != "pdcchCfiMode")
        .Skip(1).Take(1).FirstOrDefault(),
```

Answer (score 1):

Try code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            List<XElement> attributes = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "attributes").ToList();

            XNamespace esNs = attributes.FirstOrDefault().GetNamespaceOfPrefix("es");

            List<CellName> cells = attributes.Select(x => new CellName() {
                cellId = (int)x.Element(esNs + "cellId"),
                crsGain = (int)x.Element(esNs + "crsGain")
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
    public class CellName
    {
        public int cellId { get; set; }
        public int crsGain { get; set; }
    }

}
```